# VS2010 Express: Theme "New Item..." Stylesheet; Where Is It?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, stylesheet

Started checking out VS2010 Express. I have it installed on my home laptop and my work PC. This "problem" occurs on both systems. In past versions of VS I thought I was able to add style sheets to a theme by right-clicking on the theme folder, selecting "New Item...", then clicking the Style Sheet item. In VS2010 Express, Style Sheet is not present as an option. Only Skin, XML, and XSLT are present.

Is there a way to add Style Sheet to the list of selectable items? My current workaround is to create a style sheet outside of the theme folder, then drag it into the theme folder.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is not present when developing a "Web Site" as opposed to a "New Project"

Answer (score 0):

What [edition of VS2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/) are you using? The [Visual Web Developer](http://www.asp.net/vwd/) should have CSS (which I assume you're looking for).

Comment: VWD Express 2010. If I right-click on the main project or any of the folders, Style Sheet is present in the list of items I can add. If I right-click a Theme folder, it is not. As I mentioned, the only file types available when adding to the theme using the "New Item..." dialog are skin, xml, & xslt. Is there a configuration file somewhere I can adjust to get stylesheets to show as well?

Comment: I think you need to add a subfolder in the `App_Themes` folder, then add it to the subfolder.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I am attempting to add to my "Default" theme within the "App_Themes" folder.